How to efficiently left merge two large Dask dataframes without matching on index and while retaining partitioning in left dataframe?
I have the following two dataframes:
df_1 is a Dask dataframe containing a col_to_merge. It consists of many partitions but does not have known divisions nor an index. It is possible for me to create an arbitrary index if necessary. I do want the ordering and partitioning of this dataframe to be retained.
df_2 is another very large Dask dataframe. This dataframe is indexed on col_to_merge and has known divisions.
Now I want to do the following operation:
df_1 = dd.merge(left=df_1,
                right=df_2,
                how='left',
                left_on='col_to_merge'
                right_index=True)

Simply calling this merge works, however the result of df_1 gets a completely different partitioning (trying to match that of df_2), which is not the goal.
I have currently solved this by doing:

Create an arbitrary index and divisions on df_1
Perform the merge
Restore the order of df_1 by calling set_index with this arbitrary index and divisions

This produces the expected result but feels a bit hacky and is very expensive to run.
Do you have a good suggestion on how to tackle this case?
